# Does running an older Windows system restore point wipe out more recent ones?

Tags: restore

I have a number of automatically created System Restore Points on a Windows machine.

If I choose to run an older restore point, will the machine then no longer be able to access a more recent restore point?

Or are restore points held in a partition that is unaffected when running a restore?

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old restore points are only automatically deleted and replaced by
new restore points if the drive is out of space. There is no other reason
for deleting restore points.

The answer is then that newer restore points will stay even if you have
rolled back to an older one, and I have done this in the past.
You should just be careful not to run out
of the percentage of disk space allocated to restore points
while doing that.

Note that although the restore algorithm is pretty good, you might
encounter unwanted artifacts while going back and forth between
restore points. It's best to only rollback if you absolutely need to.

Comment: Great - that's exactly what I needed to know harrymc; thank you..Incidentally, if I run CMD rstrui I get 6 recent Automatic Restore Points, Type; System, and then ticking Show More RPs gives me a lot more, all earlier ones described as "System Image Restore Point" Type: Backup, They go back to the original Windows installation. But in C-Clean it only shows the 6 recent ones. Do you think these older ones are still there, even though the original backups are long gone?

Comment: I don't use CCleaner, but I find it hard to believe that so much disk space is taken up by restore points.

Comment: I've got about 124GB of restore points in a 1TB SDD, with 200GB space to spare.

Comment: Then it's entirely possible - each restore point may typically take up, say, a couple of GB. With 124GB (wow!) you should have several dozens of them.

Comment: Indeed I do have a few dozen - so thank you. I'm looking to delete a good few of them, but it's trickier if C-Clean can't see them.  I'm hoping one of the other methods in https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/selectively-delete-system-restore-points/ will work.